# React.js router rendering different body tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have several different react components. I started using react router. Everything is working fine, except I can't overcome one problem. I am rendering my components to index.html file which looks like this:

```
<body> 
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

I am rendering to id="app". Everything is fine as I mentioned but the problem is that some components require different body tags, because it is tied with design, like:

```
<body class="page-landing">
</body>
```

Is it possible to somehow pass body options through router? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'page-landing';
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = '';
}
```

When mounting component I did that it changes body tags class and when unmounting leaving it empty.

Answer (score 1):

Style a container div for each component you want personalized css:

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-landing"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

and have something like:

```
render((
    <Route path="/" component={MyApp}>
      <IndexRoute component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
    </Route>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Let `body` manage only css you want to be global across your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it just partially solved my problem. If I wrap my component with div tags, and leave body empty, I get a big empty box before component.

Comment: You do not need to leave ```body``` empty. Do like you did and render ```<div id="app"></div>``` inside it.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not very clear. I have three components: Login, LandingPage and GamePage. Login and LandingPage require that page-landing in body tag. GamePage does not. If I leave page-landing in index Login and Landing works fine, but GamePage gets messed up. If I remove page-landing, then GamePage works fine, but Login and Landing don't. Clearing body, wrapping Landing and Login with your offered divs made things better, but not perfect, because I don't know why but empty black space appears before Login and Landing page components, while everything below it looks as it should.